# Scala: initializing vertexes of a graph

Tags: list, scala, graph

I have something like this:

```
def vertices: List[Vertex] = List()
def edges: List[Edge] = List()
def adjMatrix: Array[Array[Int]] = Array.ofDim[Int](vertices.size, vertices.size)
def addVertex(lbl: Char) = {
    val vertex = new Vertex(lbl)
     vertex :: vertices
     vertex
}
class Vertex(label: Char) {
  val visited: Boolean = false
  def echo() = print(label)
}
```

when I want to create nodes like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val node1 = g.addVertex('A')
    val node2 = g.addVertex('B')
    val node3 = g.addVertex('C')

    println(g.vertices.size) // the result is 0 ???!!!
}
```

I do not know why the list `vertices` isn't filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in the method:

```
def addVertex(lbl: Char) = {
    val vertex = new Vertex(lbl)
    vertex :: vertices // This does nothing
    vertex
}
```

You don't change the list vertices. You just produce a new list `vertex :: vertices`, but you throw it immediately away.

Please try changing the method to the following:

```
def addVertex(lbl: Char) = {
    val vertex = new Vertex(lbl)
    vertices = vertex :: vertices // This also changes the var vertices
    vertex
}
```

Also, the member `vertices` should be a `var` not a `def` returning always an empty list.

```
var vertices: List[Vertex] = List()
```

Here a variant of an immutable Graph:

```
case class Vortex(lbl: String)

case class Graph(vertices:Set[Vortex], edges:Set[(Vortex,Vortex)]) {
  def addVortex(vortex:Vortex) : Graph =
    Graph(vertices + vortex, edges)
  def addEdge(edge: (Vortex, Vortex)) : Graph =
    Graph(vertices + edge._1 + edge._2, edges + edge)
}
```

Comment: ahh thanks a lot. So, I needed to change also the declaration from a `def vertices` to `var vertices`.

Comment: But actually thinking about the domain (directed graph) I think that it might be better to consider an immutable class for the graph, in which the `vertices` and `edges` would be `val`s instead of `var` and the methods `addVertex` and `addEdge` would return a new immutable instance of the graph. But whether this actually is better depends on the context. Just as a rule of thumb, I prefer in Scala immutable structures, because they make the reasoning simpler and make lockless multithreading programming easier ;)

Comment: In that case I need to use a mutable data collection to hold the data, in order to get an immutable graph structure with `val`-s - right?

Comment: let say, like: `val vertices: ArrayBuffer[Vertex] = new ArrayBuffer()` ?

Comment: No. In that case the graph would still be mutable. What I meant was the the metod `addVertex` would not return the vertex, but a new graph with the vertex added. The original graph would still remain unchanged.

Comment: I have added a very simple sample of an immutable graph class.